# assign output of command to array

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, array

When I run this command:

```
cat output | grep -i state | sort | uniq | awk '{print $ 3}')
```

the output is:

```
00x1
00x5
0080
```

To assign them to an array, I did this:

```
STATUS_ARRAY=($(cat output | grep -i state | sort | uniq | awk '{print $ 3}'))
```

but it didn't work. For every, system the output of that command is different and I want to check every single one of them.
For example -- there are 21 types of status! -- this code:

```
for STATUS in "${STATUS_ARRAY=[@]}"
do
  if [ "$STATUS" == '00x1' ] && [ "$STATUS" == '00x5' ];
  then
    echo " everything is normal"
  else [ "$STATUS" == '0080' ];
    echo " check your system "
  fi 
done
```

but when array doesn't work it won't return anything. What is wrong with this?

The contents of `output` are:

```
State                                = 00x1
State                                = 00x5
State                                = 0080
```

Comment: Can you show the content (a piece of) output file?  Also, maybe you want `"${STATUS_ARRAY[@]}"`. Don't capitalize normal variables. By convention only environment variables are in capitals

Comment: when i echo array it return one word.database.its weird. -_-

Comment: Can you please show the content of the file called `output`? Also did you read my comment regarding  `"${STATUS_ARRAY[@]}"` ?  See there is no `=` sign in there.  If you want to know more about arrays, `readarray` or `mapfile` see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005

Comment: the problem is not for and if. its just an example of why i need that array. the array dont return anything. i updated my post and added output content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way how you can solve this:

Create the array

```
mapfile -t array < <(awk '{printf("%s\n", $NF)}' output)
```

Then, loop through indices and do whatever you want based on the index. e.g:

```
for status in "${array[@]}"
 do 
  if [[ $status == @(00x1|00x5) ]]
   then echo "All ok"
  else echo "All NOT ok"
  fi 
 done
```

Comment: would u please explain the part  'create array' ?...instead of output can i write a different command for example ' df -h | grep data ' ?

Comment: Sure. Instead of awk you can write any command you want. See the link i posted in my previous comment

Comment: thank you soo much for your help my friend but it didnt work.

Comment: Can you run your script with `bash -x your_script` so we can see some debugging. Also does your file  `output` have some weird line endings?  What does  `sed -n l output` say?

Comment: thank you it really helped. an error was saving in array. without awk and with sed -n i saw it and fixed it. :)

Answer (score 2):

How about using a "here string", "Parameter expansion", and a `case` ... `esac` contruct?

```
readarray -t TMP <<< $(grep -i "state" output | sort -u)
for STATUS in "${TMP[@]##* }"
  do    case $STATUS in
                00x[15]) echo "everything normal";;
                0080)    echo "check system";;
                *)       echo "error: status unknown";;
        esac
  done
check system
everything normal
everything normal
```

Comment: thank you for ur answer but it didnt work T-T

Comment: How and why "didn't it work"? It worked for me when I tested it. Without details like error msgs or description of "mis"behaviour nobody can help you.

Comment: what should i say when it doesnt return anything? if ound the problem btw. thank you for this answer. ican use it in other scripts.

Comment: "what should i say when it doesnt return anything?" You can say, I tried this but it gave an empty return. "Didn't work" doesn't really point us to what the result was versus what was expected. Maybe it returned as if successful but actually wasn't, maybe it created an array, but incorrectly formatted, etc.